# How to left align footnotes under tabularx in a minipage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes, minipage, tabularx

I am new to LaTeX, trying to create a table using a tabularx in a two column format. I am creating the table in a minipage so that footnotes can appear at the bottom. Everything works out fine, but the footnotes under the table are right aligned, I prefer them left aligned with the table. I browsed through several posts and forums, but couldn't figure out. Any suggestions would help.

Regards,
Radhika

```
    \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran} 
    \usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
    \listfiles
    \begin{document}

    \makeatletter
     \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
     \parindent 1em
     \noindent
    %\hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
     \hbox{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
    \makeatother

    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

    \begin{table}

    X\dotfill X

    \begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
    X\dotfill X
    \centering
    \caption{Questionnaire summary}
    \begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth} {l c C C L} 
    \toprule
     \textbf{PID}\footnote{Participant ID}&\textbf{Challenge}\footnote{on a five-point Likert Scale 1-Not at all challenging and 5-Very challenging} &\textbf{Difference}\footnote{difference perceived by the participant as the movement progressed from \textit{source} to \textit{target}} &\textbf{Usefulness of embedded object}\footnote{on a five-point Likert Scale 1-Not at all useful and 5-Very useful} &\textbf{Point toughest to reach}\footnote{brackets indicate the Segment number corresponding to the point} \\
   \midrule
     PID1&2&Yes&3&6 (Seg 5)\\
     PID2&4&No&5&2 (Seg 1)\\
     PID3&3&Yes&4&4 (Seg 3)\\
     PID4&3&No&4&2 (Seg 1)\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{questionnaire}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}


*File List*
IEEEtran.cls 2012/11/21 V1.8c by Harald Hanche-Olsen and Anders Christensen
ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
tabularx.sty 1999/01/07 v2.07 `tabularx' package (DPC)
array.sty 2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
booktabs.sty 2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
```

Not sure where things are going wrong?

[image: Table image generated]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please complement your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) illustrating your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. If I compile your current code with `tabularx` and `booktabs`, the footnotes are flushleft.

Comment: It turns out that `IEEEtran.cls 2012/11/21 V1.8c by Harald Hanche-Olsen and Anders Christensen ` Is a modified IEEEtran class distributed (unfortunately) by some conference template. Deleting so that latex uses the standard IEEEtran produces a more normal layout.

Answer (score 3):

The footnote setting is controlled by the class in use (which you didn't show) Please always post complete documents. In `article` and `IEEEtran` class footnotes are set flush left but indented by 1.8em, you can remove the indent as below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
%    \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
    \hbox{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}

X\dotfill X

 \begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
X\dotfill X

  \centering
   \caption{Questionnaire summary}
   \begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth} {l c C C L} 
   \toprule
   \textbf{PID}\footnote{Participant ID}&\textbf{Challenge}\footnote{on a five-point Likert Scale 1-Not at all challenging and 5-Very challenging} &\textbf{Difference}\footnote{difference perceived by the participant as the movement progressed from \textit{source} to \textit{target}} &\textbf{Usefulness of embedded object}\footnote{on a five-point Likert Scale 1-Not at all useful and 5-Very useful} &\textbf{Point toughest to reach}\footnote{brackets indicate the Segment number corresponding to the point} \\
   \midrule
    PID1&2&Yes&3&6 (Seg 5)\\
    PID2&4&No&5&2 (Seg 1)\\
    PID3&3&Yes&4&4 (Seg 3)\\
    PID4&3&No&4&2 (Seg 1)\\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \label{questionnaire}
 \end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

The above image was generated with IEEETran 1.6 (2007) the footnote code in 1.8 (2012) is slightly different but the above definition is still appropriate if you want the footnote numbers flush left, and the image is essentially unchanged. `\listfiles` output: (Note that this is a slightly newer version than you reported 2012/12/27 instead of 2012/11/21 , perhaps something got fixed...

```
 *File List*
IEEEtran.cls    2012/12/27 V1.8 by Michael Shell
  ot1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
tabularx.sty    1999/01/07 v2.07 `tabularx' package (DPC)
   array.sty    2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
```

Comment: \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

Comment: I am using \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}, your solution doesn't seem to work in my document.

Comment: Well that's why we always ask people to post _complete_ documents in their questions. I have that class, I'll have a look what it does

Comment: It works for me in IEEEtran, see updated image

Comment: I copied and pasted the updated code into a fresh document (just the piece of code I can see in your answer), it wouldn't work. It is a two column format. And apart from the alignment of the footnotes, another difference I see in my table and your image is 'TABLE 1 QUESTIONNAIRE SUMMARY' appear in the same line, not in two lines as shown in your image.

Comment: When I copy and paste the updated code by you, I get the table with right aligned footnotes as before. Here is the \listfiles output from my document: IEEEtran.cls 2012/11/21 V1.8c by Harald Hanche-Olsen and Anders Christensen
ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
tabularx.sty 1999/01/07 v2.07 `tabularx' package (DPC)
array.sty 2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
booktabs.sty 2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of IEEEtran class, the one used by you, no luck. I am unable to upload image as I am a new user, but the footnotes are still right aligned to the table. I updated the script and filelist, pl. have a look.

Comment: I uploaded the image and removed the ! as adviced

Comment: I have no idea how you got that, I'll ping some of the regulars in the chat room see if they can try on their systems.

Comment: You could email me the log file if you want (google David Carlisle and you should get my gmail account details)

Comment: I emailed the .log and .tex files

Comment: arrived, will look this evening

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution I have found is to simply use `\hspace` :

```
\begin{table} 
   \centering 

   \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccccccccccc@{}}
      % table contents here
   \end{tabular}  

   \caption{Caption text here.} 
   \hspace{-13.5em}\small\textsuperscript{*Footnote text here.}
\end{table}
```